# How should GATT_CMD_STARTED (status=134) be interpreted?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on an android app where I need to communicate with a bluetooth LE device and in the middle of the communication I receive a callback:

```
onCharacteristicWrite()
```

...which is expected. But the status of the operation is 134 instead of 0 (=success).

This GATT status constant is not defined in the official API but here is a translation in one of many unofficial lists:

> ```
> public static final int GATT_CMD_STARTED = 134;
> ```
>
> **See:** https://code.google.com/r/naranjomanuel-opensource-broadcom-ble/source/browse/framework/java/src/com/broadcom/bt/service/gatt/GattConstants.java?r=983950f9b35407446bf082633d70c7655c206d22

The consequence, that I can see, in my app is that I do not get an expected callback to:

```
onCharacteristicChanged()
```

Does anybody know what **GATT_CMD_STARTED** means? Is it an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of the following function taken from the bludroid sources hint that something is not working correctly in your GATT server.

Commands seem to "queue up" there, as there must be pending requests or value confirmations as hinted in the comment before the `if(...)` clause.

It might be worth checking what exactly is going on before you do the `writeCharacteristic(...)` as it seems to not finish correctly or create hiccups in your server.

```
/*******************************************************************************
**
** Function         attp_cl_send_cmd
**
** Description      Send a ATT command or enqueue it.
**
** Returns          GATT_SUCCESS if command sent
**                  GATT_CONGESTED if command sent but channel congested
**                  GATT_CMD_STARTED if command queue up in GATT
**                  GATT_ERROR if command sending failure
**
*******************************************************************************/
tGATT_STATUS attp_cl_send_cmd(tGATT_TCB *p_tcb, UINT16 clcb_idx, UINT8 cmd_code, BT_HDR *p_cmd)
{
    tGATT_STATUS att_ret = GATT_SUCCESS;

    if (p_tcb != NULL)
    {   
        cmd_code &= ~GATT_AUTH_SIGN_MASK;

        /* no pending request or value confirmation */
        if (p_tcb->pending_cl_req == p_tcb->next_slot_inq ||
            cmd_code == GATT_HANDLE_VALUE_CONF)
        {
            att_ret = attp_send_msg_to_l2cap(p_tcb, p_cmd);
            if (att_ret == GATT_CONGESTED || att_ret == GATT_SUCCESS)
            {
                /* do not enq cmd if handle value confirmation or set request */
                if (cmd_code != GATT_HANDLE_VALUE_CONF && cmd_code != GATT_CMD_WRITE)
                {
                    gatt_start_rsp_timer (clcb_idx);
                    gatt_cmd_enq(p_tcb, clcb_idx, FALSE, cmd_code, NULL);
                }
            }
            else
                att_ret = GATT_INTERNAL_ERROR;
        }
        else
        {
            att_ret = GATT_CMD_STARTED;
            gatt_cmd_enq(p_tcb, clcb_idx, TRUE, cmd_code, p_cmd);
        }
    }
    else
        att_ret = GATT_ERROR;

    return att_ret;
}
```

Starts at line 469 in [android sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/master/stack/gatt/att_protocol.c).
The native GATT error and statuscodes can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/master/stack/include/gatt_api.h).

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled still. The previous callbacks all returned GATT_SUCCESS which to me indicates that there are no issues. To my knowledge there is no way to ask the GATT server if it's ready to receive more work or not

Comment: Can you supply more information on the gatt server? Any clue about the services or characteristics properties? Try to call getPermissions() and getProperties() on the characteristics you try to write, maybe it gives more information. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html for its methods and return values.